# How can I obtain survival times in coxph in R?

Tags: r, predictive-models, cox-model

I am using the following code with my data in order to obtain some predictions in R with a Cox model.

```r
model_cox <- coxph(Surv(time,status) ~ ., data = data_Training)
pred <- predict(model_cox, data_Testing, type = 'lp')
```

I get some numbers which correspond to log hazard ratios (I think). But my *time* variable is in terms of days, and I want to compare the predictions with the real time in order to validate the model.

How could I get the predictions in terms of days, or transform the real *time* variable in terms of the linear predictions of hazard ratios, and then compare them?

Answer (score 3):

From a Cox model you get log hazard ratios because you do not estimate the baseline hazard. If you want to get predictions for the expected survival times, you can use accerelated failure time models. These are provided via function `survreg()`.

Comment: Okay. But how can I validate my model with Cox response? I mean I would want to classify in 1 or 0 (die or not) depending on a threshold I set, and compare it with my real data in someway.